# The vanilla JS equivalent of jQuery's last() not working

Tags: javascript

I was working on a chat application but I wrote it using jQuery and wanted to stop doing that. I had to write stuff in vanilla JS and it works except for one persistent problem. I can't properly append the input from a user's input inside the last div that gets appended.

The value from an input gets appended inside a div that also gets appended, but it's always the first div. All the other divs that get appended will just become empty.

```
var input;

function sendResponse() {

    input = document.getElementById("input").value;

    document.getElementById('window').innerHTML += '<div class="userMessageC"></div>';
    document.getElementsByClassName('userMessageC:last > div:nth-child(2)').innerHTML += input;
    document.getElementsByClassName('userMessage')[0].lastChild.innerHTML += input;

    outputResponse(input);
}
```

`document.getElementsByClassName('userMessage')[0].lastChild.innerHTML += input` used to be `$("userMessage:last").append();` while `last()` also worked. I can't get it work with vanilla JS, I don't know which element to select. LastChild or lastElementChild don't work.

[Here's a jsfiddle to see what I mean](https://jsfiddle.net/zelm25/yj59ums1/)

Comment: You can't use selectors in `getElementsByClassName`. Use `document.querySelector()`.

Comment: And you need a `.` before the class name in a selector.

Comment: there's no nth-child(2) anyways, even if you used the selector, and (userMessage)[0] is always the first one (you're referencing the first match in the array).  Also, you could just use a template string for this.  If you want to work with dom elements, you should use createElement.  There's no need to search the DOM for the element you just apppended every time

Comment: @user120242 There is `nth-child(2)` actually. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child . Are you saying that that's not available in javascript?

Comment: @JakeParis made a mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just using a template string to insert the variable.

I've modified your DOM traversal to work, although in this case it's unnecessary.

```js
//globals 
var input;

function sendResponse() {

    input = document.getElementById("input").value;

    document.getElementById('window').innerHTML += `<div class="userMessageC"><div class="userIcon"></div><div class="userMessage"><div class="userTextBalloon"><span>${input}</span></div></div></div>`;
    
    // :last -> :last-child
    document.querySelector('.userMessageC:last-child > div:nth-child(2)').innerHTML += input;
    // .lastChild will give you the text node you just inserted
    document.getElementsByClassName('userMessage')[0].querySelector('div:last-child').innerHTML += input;
    outputResponse(input);
}
```

```css
.window {
   float: left;
   width: 100%;
   margin-top: 20px;
   margin-bottom: 120px;
 }
 
 .userMessageC {
   float: left;
   width: 100%;
   position: relative;
   word-wrap: break-word;
 }
 .userMessage {
   float: left;
   font-size: 18px;
   line-height: normal;
   margin: 1% 0;
   background: black;
   padding: 1%;
   color: white;
 }
 .click {
   float: left;
   background: black;
   color: white;
   padding: 0.5%;
 }
```

```html
<div id="window">
  <div class="typeBarContainer">
    <div class="typxeBarInnerContainer">

      <div class="typeBar">
        <input id="input" type="text" placeholder="Type here"/>
      </div>
      <div class="click" onclick="sendResponse();">
        Send
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```